# Install distro to external ssd/hdd?

Tags: boot, live-usb, external-hdd

I'd like to know if it is possible to install an entire Linux distro along with its very own `/`, `/boot`, `/home`, `/etc`, `and more` onto an external ssd/hdd and boot to it just like any liveUSB. It would also have to be able to save changes from one boot up to the next. Is this possible? Are there any additional steps to undertake after running `calamares` or other installation package?

I ask because I am a petsitter/housesitter and having the option to just bring along an external drive rather than my entire setup would be very helpful. That way, I could attach the external ssd/hdd to any computer and boot up into a Linux distro set up exactly how I want as well as save any work I do while running the distro. Then upon returning home, I could mount the external live-installed-distro onto my computer and retrieve anything I worked on while away from home.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Just make sure to install the bootmanager on the external disk, too.

It is a standard installation procedure otherwise.